# Javascript / HTML banner not working

Tags: html, css, rotation, banner

I'm following this tutorial (Removed link as YouTube videos are not allowed on SO).

I can't understand why the banner wont flick through as it should, I have 4 images I intend it to flick through.

Also if anyone does solve this how can I make the images link to another page, e.g is it as simple as adding `<a href=.......>` in the `HTML` code?

### HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src:"jquery.js"></script>
<div id="banner">
    <img src="images/banner1.jpg" class="active" />
    <img src="images/banner4.jpg" />
    <img src="images/banner2.jpg" />
    <img src="images/banner3.jpg" />
</div>
```

### javascript/jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        //Get current active image
        var active = $('#banner .active');

        // If there is another image(object) left then make that image next
        // If not, go back to the first image of the banner div
        if (active.next().length > 0) var next = active.next();
        else var next = $('#banner img:first');

        //Get the next image ready by modifying the z-index
        next.css('z-index', '2');

        //Fade out the active image, then
        active.fadeOut(1000, function () {

        });
        //Move the active image to the back of the pile, show it and             remove     the active class
        active.css('z-index', '1').show().removeClass('active');
        //Make the next image the active one    
        next.css('z-index', '3').addClass('active');
    });

}, 3000);
});
```

### CSS

```
#banner {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 350px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#banner img {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
#banner img.active {
    z-index:3;
}
```

Comment: `src:"jquery.js"` should be `src="jquery.js"`.

Comment: rectified but didn't fix it, is it searching for a jquery file? i've added this in after ive built half the home page, so do i need to add a 'jquery.js' file or how does this work?

Comment: You put the `jquery.js` in the same place as your homepage and that link will work. You also have to many `}` in your jQuery part. I would go back to the tutorial and find where you went wrong. One more thing, I would recommend not using videos tutorials can be very hard to follow compared to text.

Comment: If you get it working this is what it will look like [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/E2Kgu/) Thats your code just working. (I used different sized images just to show that it is working, you would use the same size.)

Comment: thanks, also it says syntax error on the 2nd to last line (line above </script>

Comment: Because its not need `});` <--- dont need it. Look at how many you open and close. The indentation even tells you that. Look at the demo I gave you, thats fixed.

Comment: added your script in and still did not work, i added </script> on the end of your indentation and no change, now gone back to my original code above however without the }); and the syntax error but that still doesnt work! im very confused now

Comment: Have you looked at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/E2Kgu/)? You can clearly see its working so what I said **does** work. This is pretty simple (to link up a jQuery file), if you cant work that out or basic syntax you should go start from the basics. Start with `HTML` and `CSS` then move to `Javascript` followed by `jQuery` (my recommendation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so to start with you don't have your script linked up.

You have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src:"jquery.js"></script>
```

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

As you have just put `jquery.js` that means if you homepage (whatever page is using it) is in `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Website` then `jquery.js` also needs to be in that same folder.

---

Then we move to the jQuery, its all ok untill the end of it. You close it with `}, 3000);`
but then try to close it again using `});`. The indentation also gives it away.

So when we fix that we get this [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/E2Kgu/)

Comment: thanks for the help, i've corrected those but it will still not work!

Comment: Nothing... I fixed it. Hence the demo of it working. Try using `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` instead. I guess you just haven't linked the file up. So use the web version.

Comment: @user3086732 Also don't change your OP it helps other people to find similar problems.

Comment: thanks ruddy ! had the end of the code indentation before the timing so the time wasnt calculated and resulted in the crazy flashing cycle! perfect answer and rapid response much appreciated!!

Comment: @user3086732 Change `3000` (3 seconds) to something else.

Comment: one more thing, how come only the last image fades?

Comment: @user3086732 Because the code isn't inside the fade [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/E2Kgu/1/)

Comment: @user3086732 Glad I could help. When and if you can +1 this answer that would be good :)

Comment: i think it requires 15 rep, i've said that that is the correct answer if that helps!